# SQL GROUP_BY additional column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following Postgres SQL query:

```
SELECT movement_id, counter, MAX(standardized_output) AS standardized_output 
FROM "outputs" 
WHERE "outputs"."user_id" = 1 AND "outputs"."movement_id" = 1 AND (counter in (1,3,5)) 
GROUP BY movement_id, counter
```

This nicely produces three rows for me.

However I also want to pull in the relevant `done_at` column. Adding `done_at` to the `SELECT` and `GROUP_BY` ends up returning hundreds of rows however; I just want the three rows that the above query returns, with the appropriate `done_at` field for the output row that was found by the `MAX` function.

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE with  ROW_NUMBER

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT movement_id, counter, standardized_output ,done_at,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY movement_id, counter  ORDER BY standardized_output DESC) as RN
FROM "outputs" 
WHERE "outputs"."user_id" = 1 AND "outputs"."movement_id" = 1 AND (counter in (1,3,5)) 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the field `done_at` with the `max` value you don't need to add it on the `group by` clause you have to add it with the max function as bellow

```
SELECT movement_id, 
       counter, 
       MAX(standardized_output) AS standardized_output,
       MAX(done_at)
  FROM "outputs" 
 WHERE "outputs"."user_id" = 1 
   AND "outputs"."movement_id" = 1 
   AND counter in (1,3,5)
 GROUP BY movement_id, counter
```

You can use multiple aggregate columns on the same sql. I think that `done_at` is a date column and because of that you are getting hundreds of rows.

Comment: This would not necessarily return the value of `done_at` where `standardized_output` is at its maximum value.

Comment: @BenSmith For each combination of `(movement_id, counter)` you will get the maximum value of `standardized_output` and that of `done_at`. If these maximum values happen to come from the same row, then it will work, but what if `done_at` is some low value where `standardized_output` is at its maximum? So it may work for some, perhaps even most or all of your data, but it may also return values for  `standardized_output` and `done_at` in a combination that is not provided by a single row.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a sub query derived table:

```
SELECT t2.movement_id, t2.counter, t2.standardized_output, t1.done_at
FROM "outputs" t1
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT movement_id, counter, MAX(standardized_output) AS standardized_output 
      FROM "outputs" 
     WHERE "outputs"."user_id" = 1 AND "outputs"."movement_id" = 1 
       AND (counter in (1,3,5)) 
  GROUP BY movement_id, counter) t2
ON t1.movement_id = t2.movement_id
```